# How to position the cursor with a click when running mysql in terminal on mac os x

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts

Holding the option key and clicking in terminal lets me position the cursor with the mouse.

I'd like to be able to do the same thing when I'm running mysql in terminal, but it doesn't work.  Is there some kind of setting or escape character that will allow me to use the option click method?  Or is there another way to click to position the cursor?

I typically write a long command in mysql with an accidental error, then I hit the up arrow to get that command again, so I can edit it and fix the error.  It would be nice if I can use the mouse to click at the spot where the error is, instead of using the left/right arrow key to move the cursor.

For example:

```
mysql>
CREATE TABLE test_table (col1 INT, blah blah, col3 INT);

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'blah, col3 int)' at line 1
```

After seeing that error, I'd like to hit up to get the command in the prompt again, and then just click at the word 'blah' to start editing.

Comment: Can't answer this but you might want to check out 'Sequel Pro' its a free GUI for mysql on OS X and there is really nothing related to mysql you can't manage with it.

Comment: Alt+click works fine on my machine.

Comment: @zneak, thanks for the input. I did a little more testing, and it looks like I can now get it to work only some times.  On my machine, if the command is longer than one line and wraps to another line (like when making the terminal window smaller), then I can't click in any of the first lines.  For some reason, I can only click to change the cursor position on the last line.  I wonder if this happens on your machine also?

Comment: This is because alt+click simulates as many arrow key inputs as needed to move to the character you're pointing. If you don't click on the current line, it will input up and down arrow key codes. This is desirable when working with interactive editors like `vim` or `emacs`, but not when you deal with "normal" prompts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alt+click works to position the cursor.

As @zneak points out in the comments above, it does so by simulating many arrow key inputs.

So, when I tried to position the cursor a few lines up in a multi line command, it would replace the current command with previous commands as if I pressed the up arrow key.  So now, if I need to move the cursor one line up, I just alt click to the beginning of the line and press the left arrow key to get to the previous line.